# Is there any way to use first and last functions in rpd for one measure column in OBIEE?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, repository, obiee

I am building an rpd and one of the requirements was the following. We have one measure column **DEBIT_ALL** in a fact table . This is a sum of all debits that client had since the creation of that client's account. That is this sum always accumulated whenever there is an debit operation.

So in OBIEE users create analysis to see the Debit_all value for some period using date1 and date2 in filters, or just giving month or year value. The easiest way to calcute this amount for some period is to substract sum in date1-1 from sum in date2.

That is value of debit_all measure for period from date1 to date2 is equal to:

**value in date2 - value in (date1-1)**

Can we do this in rpd admin tool? I had an idea to use first and last functions but couldnt find a proper way.

Comment: Trying to understand here: "just giving month or year value" - do you mean "Month To Date" / "Year To Date" or monthly/yearly aggregations or something completely different?

Comment: Did you give up on this?

Comment: @Chris, sorry for too late response. By "just giving month or year value" I mean user can apply different filters. For example user may want to see all debits for current month(month to date) or for some period from one specific date till some other date. He can also give a year period. Which one of these cases are solvable in OBIEE?

Comment: All the cases are solvable, but you need to be clearer with your requirement. The devil is in the detail and without an exact target you're bound to risk starting on a wrong path.

Comment: @Chirs,I see, let me clarify it then. The requirement is the following. There are two date boundaries. The value of all debits between these two dates should be calculated as value in date2 - value in (date1 -1). Is it done in obiee by using filters or should we create some repository variables to solve this?